# Google Analytics Admin API in Advanced Google Services

Tags: google-apps-script

I've seen that Google Analytics Admin API is in an is an early preview version. Is there a timeline when this is going to be avaliable on the Advance Google Services for Google Apps Script?

BR,

Comment: You can make calls to the API using `UrlFetchApp.fetch()`. Check out the [reference documentation for the Google Analytics Admin API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest) to see which endpoints you'll need to use.

Comment: Thanks. I've worked for listing the properties but I got stuck [creating properties in GA4](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68575280/create-a-google-analytics-4-propery-with-google-apps-script)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Google Analytics admin](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1#account_summaries) is currently in beta.

The beta version is now also available on Google app script.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

In the [summary page of the API](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1) it says to subscribe to the [Google Analytics API Notify Group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/google-analytics-api-notify) for announcements.  It is likely that Google does not publish dates or timelines for releases.