# Create a Google Analytics 4 propery with Google Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

Based on [this documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties/create) I'm trying to create a GA4 Property in Google Apps Script:

```
  var service = getService();
  if (service.hasAccess()) {

    var apiURL = "https://analyticsadmin.googleapis.com/v1alpha/properties";

    var resource = {
      "displayName": "Automating GA4 creation",
      "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
      "currencyCode": "USD",
      "parent": "accounts/123"
    };

    Logger.log(resource);

    var headers = {
      "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()
    };
    
    var options = {
      "headers": headers,
      "method" : "POST",
      "muteHttpExceptions": true,
      "resource": resource
    };
    
    var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(apiURL, options);

    Logger.log(response);

  } else {
    var authorizationUrl = service.getAuthorizationUrl();
    Logger.log('Open the following URL and re-run the script: %s', authorizationUrl);
    Browser.msgBox('Open the following URL and re-run the script: ' + authorizationUrl)
  }    
}
```

But I get this error:

```
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "The value for the 'parent' field was invalid but must be in format 'accounts/123'.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT"
  }
}
```

my response format is OK according to [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/config/admin/v1/rest/v1alpha/properties)

This is my `Logger.log(resource)` :

```
{parent=accounts/123, displayName=Automating GA4 creation, currencyCode=USD, timeZone=America/Los_Angeles}
```

NOTES:

1- Due to privacy I have replace the my Google Analytics Account ID by `123`.

2- The OAuth works because I've been able to list properties.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`UrlFetchApp.fetch()` does not recognize the `resource` field in the `options` object. You need to change that to `payload`. Moreover, you also need to `JSON.stringify()` the resource before passing it to the `payload` property under the options object and you also have to set the `contentType` property to `application/json`.

So your `options` object should look something like this:

```js
var resource = {
    "displayName": "Automating GA4 creation",
    "timeZone": "America/Los_Angeles",
    "currencyCode": "USD",
    "parent": "accounts/123"
};

var headers = {
    "Authorization": "Bearer " + getService().getAccessToken()
};
    
var options = {
    "headers": headers,
    "contentType":"application/json",
    "method" : "POST",
    "muteHttpExceptions": true,
    "payload": JSON.stringify(resource)
};
```

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, however I get an error 400: due to the JSON payload request: Invalid JSON payload received.
"details": 
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": 
            "description": "Invalid JSON payload received. Unknown name "displayName":"Automating GA4 creation", [....], \"parent\":\"accounts/123\"}\": Cannot bind query parameter. Field '{\"displayName\":\"Automating GA4 creation\",\"timeZone\":\"America/Los_Angeles\",\"currencyCode\":\"USD\",\"parent\":\"accounts/123\"}' could not be found in request message."